# ALAMOFIRE response image data for multipart image

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have written a function which uploads two multipart images on the server and the server merges these 2 images and returns 1 whole image as response.

> This is the function

```
func apiObjectInPainting(image: UIImage, maskedimage: UIImage,completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image1.jpg")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(maskedimage,1.0) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image2.jpg")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }

        let fileURL1 = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image1.jpg")
        let fileURL2 = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image2.jpg")
        NSLog("Files being stored @\(fileURL1)")

        KVNProgress.show(withStatus: "Replacing Object")

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(fileURL1, withName: "image")
            multipartFormData.append(fileURL2, withName: "image")
            multipartFormData.append("SECKEY".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "Authorization")
        },
                         usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                         to:"[URL]",
                         method:.post,
                         encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.response { response in
                                    debugPrint(response)
                                    KVNProgress.dismiss()
                                    completion(true)
                                }
                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                KVNProgress.dismiss()

                                print(encodingError)
                            }
        })

    }
```

In encodeCompletion I have

```
case .success(let upload, _, _):
      upload.response { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            KVNProgress.dismiss()
            completion(true)
      }
```

But in the response I get,

```
    Alamofire.DefaultDataResponse(request: Optional([URL]), response: nil, data: Optional(0 bytes), error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000446450 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[URL], NSErrorFailingURLKey=[URL], _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}), timeline: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 509658047.051, "Initial Response Time": 509658047.386, "Request Completed Time": 509658166.018, "Serialization Completed Time": 509658166.021, "Latency": 0.335 secs, "Request Duration": 118.967 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.003 secs, "Total Duration": 118.970 secs }, _metrics: Optional((Task Interval) <_NSConcreteDateInterval: 0x6000004223c0> (Start Date) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000 + (Duration) 118.966891 seconds = (End Date) 2017-02-24 19:42:46 +0000
(Redirect Count) 0
(Transaction Metrics) (Request) <NSURLRequest: 0x600000016020> { URL: [URL] }
(Response) (null)
(Fetch Start) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Domain Lookup Start) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Domain Lookup End) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Connect Start) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Secure Connection Start) (null)
(Secure Connection End) (null)
(Connect End) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Request Start) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Request End) 2017-02-24 19:41:47 +0000
(Response Start) 2017-02-24 19:40:47 +0000
(Response End) (null)
(Protocol Name) http/1.1
(Proxy Connection) NO
(Reused Connection) NO
(Fetch Type) Network Load

))
```

Please help me in getting proper response as currently it is not successfull.

Comment: The error returned is "Response timed out." Maybe because that method takes a long time to complete. Can you test with a simple method that just returns some static response?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you are uploading large amount of data, so your request is timeout. You can increase timeout interval and its work for you.

Here is the code:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10800 // seconds
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10800 // seconds

alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried the code but same issue, `let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10800
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10800

        manager.upload(multipartFormData:{ `